# Css Box Layout Main Content At 100%

Tags: css

How would you make the main_content stretch to the header, footer, right and left side bar.
Just looking for a 3 column layout with header and footer. I've been searching and haven't found any examples that do this.

```
<style type="text/css">
#header
{
    height:100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#left_side_bar
{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
}
#main_content
{
    border: 1px solid green; 
    float: left;
    width: ?;
    height: ?;

}
#right_side_bar
{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width:100px;
    height: 300px;
    float: right;
}
#footer
{
    border: 1px solid blue; 
    clear:both;
    height: 100px;
}

</style>

<div id="header"></div>
<div id="left_side_bar"></div>
<div id="main_content"></div>
<div id="right_side_bar"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Which browser(s) does this need to work in?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear, which version of IE as a minimum does this need to work in? Is IE6 support required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nkj5d/1/) with `position:fixed`, although there are plenty of sites out there which can generate the mark-up and CSS for you. For example the very nice [CSS Layout Generator](http://csslayoutgenerator.com/)

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
#Header {
float: left;
clear: both;
width: 100%;
}

#Left_Side_Bar {
float: left;
width: 10%;
}

#Main_Content {
float: left;
width: 80%;
}

#Right_Side_Bar {
float: left;
width: 10%;
}

#Footer {
float: left;
clear: both;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This actually didn't work see link -> [css_test](http://i1114.photobucket.com/albums/k535/tzat6/boxtext.png)

Comment: In your edit you added fixed width to the side bars and my example doesn't work with fixed widths. But the other solutions given by andyb and jasalguero should provide you with a working setup :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find example of most of the 3 column layouts (fixed, fluid, mixed...) -> [CSS Layouts](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/category/C10/)